# Session not properly being passed for login and authentication

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, session, server

I am trying to learn how sessions work.  I know that  in the server side,   req.session.user = { id: 1, username: 'user1' }; is being read correctly but when I hit the endpoint /check-session req.session.user is undefined.

> Login successful Session status: Session expired or not authenticated.

How is session supposed to be handled?  Does the client receive the session and is automatically sent over in req for /check-session?

The logs that come out are
// client.js
const axios = require('axios');

```
// Function to simulate user login
async function login() {
  try {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login');
    console.log('Login successful');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Login failed:', error.message);
  }
}

// Function to check session status
async function checkSession() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/check-session');
    console.log('Session status:', response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error checking session:', error.message);
  }
}

// Simulate user login and check session after a short delay
async function main() {
  await login();
  setTimeout(checkSession, 5000); // Check session status after 1 second
}

main();
```

Server Code

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(session({
  secret: 'your_secret_key', // Change this to a secure secret key
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  // For simplicity, let's consider authentication successful for any request to /login
  req.session.user = { id: 1, username: 'user1' };
  res.send('Login successful from server');
});

app.get('/check-session', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.send('Session active');
  } else {
    res.send('Session expired or not authenticated');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`express-session` sets a unique ID in cookie, session data itself is stored on server-side.

Since you're using `axios`, make sure you have set the `withCredentials` flag so that your `post` request includes the cookie.

You can use the browser's Developer Tools to inspect the request and check if the cookie is included when you make the call.